# Does Ahead-of-Time Compilation need angular-cli as a production dependency?

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, platform-server

Going from the official instructions found here https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler, it recommends installing the following npm dependencies with the command:

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save
```

This adds both @angular/compiler-cli and @angular/platform-server to the dependencies section of your package.json

Are these dependencies needed for production?  Or can they equivalently go in the dev-dependencies section of the package.json file?

Comment: When you generate a project with angular-cli, it actually puts `@angular/compiler-cli` in devDependencies. `@angular/platform-server` is for server side rendering, so I would imagine that might make sense for it to be a dependency, and not a devDependency. Haven't used SSR myself, so couldn't say for sure on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is: No.

`@angular/compiler-cli` doesn't need to be saved as a `dependency` it can be `devDependency` - it is needed only at the compile-time.

This is how it works in my project, but I am not using `CLI` at all. Instead of that I am using `webpack` together with `@ngtools/webpack` plugin.

You can find example here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-pwa